# The Order of images loaded in angular masonry changes each time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, load

I am using angular-masonry for my website, and the order in which images are loaded changes each time.

Is anyone familiar with angular-masonry enough to tell me how to make the order consistent?

Answer (score 1):

I'very not used angular-masonry, but looking at their docs (https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry/blob/master/README.md), I can see the "preserve-order" option. Are you using this, or can you provide some initialization code you're using?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. For some reason, I assumed it wouldn't be covered in doc............................